# How to cross compile a mobile SDK?

Tags: android, ios, sdk, cross-compiling

I have a sophisticated NLP engine that I wish to make available on mobile as an SDK for developers to use. The engine is currently a hybrid of multiple languages but we are looking to rationalise it to a single language and codebase. The answer to this question will influence the choice of language.

In particular, I wish for iOS developers to be able to call the engine using Objective C (Or perhaps Swift) and android developers to be able to use the engine in Java.

I do not want to port my engine and maintain two separate codebase for the core NLP algorithms.

While there are many options for cross compiling applications, such as [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/), [Apportable](https://www.apportable.com/), or even [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/). but none that I could see that would make it easy to cross compile an SDK.

**What approach could I take so that my core engine is cross compiled from a unique code base while still providing good Java and Objective C bindings?**

Comment: What is this engine written in? C? C++? Something else?

Comment: A hybrid mix of Python, Java and C++, but we're migrating to a single language and the answer to this question will influence the choice of language.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to port my engine and maintain two separate codebase for the core NLP algorithms

Then you need to write it in C or C++ and ensure that your code does not do anything platform-specific.

Then, you can write wrappers for it as needed, such as a JNI wrapper for use with the Android NDK, so Android developers can use your library via your wrapper's Java API.

I am not an iOS developer, and so I do not know what you might need to make a C/C++ library readily consumable via Objective-C (let alone Swift), though I imagine that there are some recipes for doing that.